# Incorporating date into this GROUP BY and INNER JOIN select statement

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to produce a list of the top 20 earners in my reward system.

The following statement works perfectly to show that:

```
SELECT
    S.User_ID As UserID,
    CONCAT(S.User_Forename, " ", S.User_Surname) AS StudentName,
    T.TotalPoints
FROM
    student S
INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT
        Datetime, Recipient_ID, SUM(Points) AS TotalPoints
      FROM
        transactions
      GROUP BY
        Recipient_ID ) T
ON
    S.User_ID = T.Recipient_ID
ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Come to think of it however, next year, I'll need to include a date range (i.e. show the top earners for that school year only).

For testing purposes, I tried to amend to the following statement which includes a `LESS THAN DATETIME` selection:

```
SELECT
    S.User_ID As UserID,
    CONCAT(S.User_Forename, " ", S.User_Surname) AS StudentName,
    T.TotalPoints
FROM
    student S
INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT
        Datetime, Recipient_ID, SUM(Points) AS TotalPoints
      FROM
        transactions
      GROUP BY
        Recipient_ID ) T
ON
    S.User_ID = T.Recipient_ID
WHERE t.Datetime < 2012-03-20
ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC
LIMIT 20
```

I've also tried this:

```
SELECT
    S.User_ID As UserID,
    CONCAT(S.User_Forename, " ", S.User_Surname) AS StudentName,
    T.TotalPoints
FROM
    student S
INNER JOIN 
    ( SELECT
        Datetime, Recipient_ID, SUM(Points) AS TotalPoints
      FROM
        transactions
      WHERE Datetime < 2012-03-20
      GROUP BY
        Recipient_ID ) T
ON
    S.User_ID = T.Recipient_ID
ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Both of those however display an empty result set.

If I do a simple `SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE Datetime < 2012-03-20`, over 25K results are returned.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: did you try a single quote around your date value?  '2012-03-20'

Comment: I'm curious about something. Maybe I'm missing something but Datetime is not in an aggregate or group by statement. What happens to it in the T subquery?

Comment: @dunc Try bluefeet's suggestion. It should work.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are missing single quotes `'` around your date value:

```
WHERE t.Datetime < '2012-03-20'
```